# SSH command to replace/convert spaces from images file with underscores in a directory

Tags: whitespace, centos7

I want to remove spaces from .jpg files and convert/replace spaces in underscores.

Current files name : image 1 2.jpg
I want it to be become: image_1_2.jpg

These are all images files inside a directory `/home/website/www/import` and there are many files with different names but I want only `.jpg` extension file to change space with underscore.

This command not worked:

```
find -name "* *.jpg" -type f | rename 's/ /_/g'
```

I run it from root and shows this :

```
rename: not enough arguments
```

Kindly provide me correct command

centos 7.5
root access

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find -exec` for something like that:

```
find ./ -name "* *.jpg" -exec rename  's/ /_/g' {} \;
```

(not tested, but it should be something like that)